# Selenium close_fds

Tags: selenium, python-3.6

Hello I am trying to run the python script below

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Julian\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
```

Upon Running it I am taken to a file named service.py and pointed to the the following

```
:Exceptions:
 - WebDriverException : Raised either when it can't start the service
   or when it can't connect to the service
"""
try:
    cmd = [self.path]
    cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,d 
                                    close_fds=(platform.system() != 'Windows'),
                                    stdout=self.log_file,
                                    stderr=self.log_file,
                                    stdin=PIPE)
```

The particular line highlighted

```
                                    close_fds=(platform.system() != 'Windows'),
```

Can someone point me in the direction of what I am supposed to do or change? Any help is strongly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: Yes I am running this on windows.

Comment: which version of chrome browser and driver you have?

Comment: latest for chrome browser and 2.26 I think

Comment: I now have  latest chrome and latest webdriver so 2.35, but the same issues still occur.

Comment: Is your question solved now?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to remove the `d`. Must have typed it by accident.

Comment: Editing the question to remove the `d` would render the question pointless as that *was* the issue. I've voted to close the question as off-topic as the problem was a simple typo. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18568269). This question will likely be deleted by the system in due course as it isn't helpful to others; the answer is correct and should stay.